# Can show me how to refactor this nested loop using java 8 streams?

Tags: java

I have two lists `parentList` and `salesList`. I need to loop on `parentList` and `salesList` and if `salesItem.Id== parentItem.Id`, add `salesItem` to new list called `inner` and set `inner` to `ChildList`

```
for (ParentModel parentItem : parentList) { //list1
    List<InnerModel> inner = new ArrayList<>(); // new list 
    for (SalesModel salesItem : salesList) {  //list2
        if (parentItem.getId() == salesItem.getID()) { // if parent item id == salesItem.id add item to new created list 
            inner.add(new InnerModel(salesItem.getServiceNameEn(),salesItem.getCashierName(), salesItem.getServiceCode()));
        }
    }
    if (inner.size() != 0) {
        parentItem.setHasChild(true);
        parentItem.setChildList(inner);
    } else
        parentItem.setHasChild(false);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that can be done. --- [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: simply try `list-stream().foreach()` and inside finding matchign ones you can use `list2.stream().filter()`.
Something to keep in mind: Streams are not always best practice. They can be slower on complex models and lot of loops and depending on the dev hard to understand.

Comment: What is innerItem? shouldn't it be salesItem?

Comment: parentItem.setHasChild method could be a calculated property based on the ChildList size

Answer (score 2):

For better performance, use Streams to convert `salesList` to a `Map`.

```java
Map<Integer, SalesModel> salesMap = salesList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SalesModel::getID));
```

After that, it can e.g. be done like this, though I don't think that's any better than a regular `for` loop.

```java
parentList.stream().forEach(p -> p.setHasChild(salesMap.containsKey(p.getId())));
parentList.stream().filter(salesMap.containsKey(p.getId()))
                   .forEach(p -> p.setChildList(salesMap.get(p.getId())));
```

Answer (score 1):

As said @Andreas, using a `Map` could lead to better performance. And I suggest using the approach with a `Map`.

But if you wanna just replace your loops with streams, you can use the next:

```java
   parentList.forEach(parentModel -> parentModel.setChildList(salesList.stream()
                .filter(sale -> sale.getId() == parentModel.getId())
                .map(InnerModel::new).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Full code example:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ParentModel> parentList = Arrays.asList(new ParentModel(1), new ParentModel(2), new ParentModel(3));
        List<SalesModel> salesList = Arrays.asList(new SalesModel(1), new SalesModel(1), new SalesModel(2));
        parentList.forEach(parentModel -> parentModel.setChildList(salesList.stream()
                .filter(sale -> sale.getId() == parentModel.getId())
                .map(InnerModel::new).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        parentList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


    private static class ParentModel {
        private final long id;
        private List<InnerModel> innerModels;

        public ParentModel(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setChildList(List<InnerModel> innerModels) {
            this.innerModels = innerModels;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringJoiner(", ", ParentModel.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                    .add("id=" + id)
                    .add("innerModels=" + innerModels)
                    .toString();
        }
    }


    private static class SalesModel {

        private final long id;

        public SalesModel(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringJoiner(", ", SalesModel.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                    .add("id=" + id)
                    .toString();
        }
    }

    private static class InnerModel {
        private final SalesModel model;

        public InnerModel(SalesModel model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringJoiner(", ", InnerModel.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                    .add("model=" + model)
                    .toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was doing the same thing! xD You can try here https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/eSE